# Filter an array of object with another array - returning two values

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter

I wanted to filter my seach by name and type when a user types on the search box however I am just getting back the names but not by type.

This is my array:

```
        const projects = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'protfolio',
            type: ['react']
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'RoboFriends',
            type: ['react']
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Background-gradient',
            type: ['html ', 'css ', 'javaScript']
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Election-map',
            type: ['html ', 'css ', 'javaScript']
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            name: 'To-Do-List',
            type: ['react']
        }
    ]
```

The function I've reacted to filter over my array and return the project name and also type

```
    const projectFilter = this.state.projects.filter( project => {
                return project.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchField.toLowerCase())
                || project.type.includes(this.state.searchField);
            })
```

Comment: but you never even filter it by type, and we don't even *know* what "type" is, `this.state.what?`

Comment: Maybe you need to do `this.state.searchField.toLowerCase()` as well for the type check, you might be inputting an upper case string there

Comment: What is the ```searchField``` can possibly be? One of the 5 names in ```project.name```?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. I checked. Make sure your searchField came as you wish.

[Check this out](https://jsfiddle.net/j659xokt/)

```
function myFunction() {
   const projects = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'protfolio',
            type: ['react']
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'RoboFriends',
            type: ['react']
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Background-gradient',
            type: ['html ', 'css ', 'javaScript']
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Election-map',
            type: ['html ', 'css ', 'javaScript']
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            name: 'To-Do-List',
            type: ['react']
        }
    ]
     const projectFilter = projects.filter( project => {
                return project.name.toLowerCase().includes('react')
                || project.type.includes('react');
            })
            document.getElementById("test").innerText = (projectFilter[2].name);
}
```